# Plotting data on maps using d3.js but without lat/long

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geocoding

I'm experimenting with d3.js and plotting data on maps.
My data only has general city/state information. It doesn't have lat/long.

Looking at the tutorials online, all the data they have is already in a geojson format.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to plot on a map without lat/long info? i.e. the map
   is able to intelligently intrepret something like "Chicago, IL"
2. If not, What is the current best practice to map general arbitrary
   location data like i have into a geojson format? I'm wondering if
   there is a better way than just manually trying to map it using some
   random source i find online.

Comment: You are looking for [*geocoding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding). There are numerous APIs around for this (many of them free): Google, Bing, MapQuest, OpenStreetMap and many others provide such services.

Comment: Thanks! geocoding looks like exactly what i'm looking for. If you make your comment an answer, i'm happy to accept it.

Comment: Well, it's not really a question suitable for SO (too broad, lack of code, off-topic, asking for external resources). It has already gathered two close votes and would have long been put on hold, had I not removed the much more popular, though irrelevant tags. That said, I think it is a valid and good question, which, on the other hand, was [asked before](/search?q=%5Bgeocoding%5D+provider+is%3Aq) on SO. Another good source of information might be [*Geographic Information Systems*](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) on SE.

Comment: Or, you could jump directly over to the [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro).